# In which class/interface readObjectNoData(), writeReplace(), readResolve() is declared?

Tags: java, java-io

During serialization/deserialization process we can define `readObjectNoData()/writeReplace()/readResolve()` to customize default serialization/deserialization behavior.

Now my question is that where are the declared? Like `readUnshared()/writeUnshared()`  are declared/defined in  `ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ObjectStreamClass hasReadObjectNoDataMethod()/hasReadResolveMethod()/hasWriteReplaceMethod()` method is define which is used to identify whether target class define the `readObjectNoData()/writeReplace()/readResolve()` methods, if so those method are invoked in `ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream.`

`ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(....
        if (obj != null && 
            slotDesc.hasReadObjectNoDataMethod() &&
            handles.lookupException(passHandle) == null)
        {
            slotDesc.invokeReadObjectNoData(obj);
        }`

`ObjectStreamClass` also declare the following fields     `private Method readObjectNoDataMethod;private Method writeReplaceMethod;private Method readResolveMethod;`

Answer (score 2):

They aren't declared in any interface: this is an extralinguistic contract. `Serializable` is a marker interface that binds a class implementing it by the contracts of the Java Serialization mechanism. The best practice is to declare a `private readResolve`, which makes it quite obvious that there can't possibly be an interface that declares it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  `writeObject()/readObject()` also marked as `private` but they are defined at `ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization mechanism uses reflection to call these fields. The detection is based on the method signatures, there is no interface for these.